# Need help making a discord bot for my server im just testing but im not sure how to get it to work properly

Tags: discord, discord.js

The discord bot im making won't work how I want it to im trying to get the bot to read a .txt file on my computer, im sure this is possible but I can't get it to work

this is the code I have

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds], partials: [Partials.Channel] });

const token = 'Removed for reasons';
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!warn')) {
    try {
      const data = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Users\\Genxn\\Documents\\Warn.txt', 'utf8');
      const warnings = JSON.parse(data);
      const args = message.content.split(' ');
      const targetUser = args[1];
      const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

      const warning = {
        user: targetUser,
        reason: reason
      };

      warnings.push(warning);

      fs.writeFileSync('C:\\Users\\Genxn\\Documents\\Warn.txt', JSON.stringify(warnings, null, 2));

      message.channel.send(`User ${targetUser} has been warned for: ${reason}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      message.channel.send('An error occurred while reading the file.');
    }
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

im just trying to make it say something in a channel (the channel # is #『』general if anyone could help me the warn thing is just because its a test also not sure if this works but this command is in the .txt file /warn user:@.cryptomaniac reason:cus im not sure if that is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't import the module 'fs'. That's why you cannot read a text file. Just add this line in the top of your code

```js
const fs = require('fs');
```

And this should work properly.